# Setting ANSI_NULLS in command text gives error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ado.net

I have to SET ANSI_NULLS and few other database options before I run some queries. So in my code

```
const string query_prefix = "SET ANSI_NULLS ON \n GO \n SET ANSI_PADDING ON \n GO \n SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON \n GO \n SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON \n GO \n SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON \n GO \n SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF \n GO \n ";
```

which I use as

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query_prefix + "SELECT UserID,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName FROM mydb.dbo.UserInfo where UserID=10277",con);
```

I added the "\n" above because SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO SET ANSI_PADDING ON GO was giving error "Incorrect syntax near GO". In management studio if GO is in a newline then I do not get the incorrect syntax error, otherwise I do. So I added "\n" but it still throws the error.

So how do I set these database options from code? I cannot use a procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GO is a batch separator in SSMS, it is not a SQL command and cannot be included in a query like this.

Answer (score 3):

- Open the connection
- Create an SqlCommand object to execute SET ANSI_NULLS ON and SET_ANSI_PADDING_ON with ExecuteNonQuery method
- Execute your select statement as separate SqlCommand in the same connection

Sample code can be found in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330684/session-setting-to-support-indexed-views). You can also set the default for these settings at the database level if appropriate for your environment.